# Python 3 - How to remove empty paragraphs on specific lines only - pythondocx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

```
from docx import Document

alphaDic =      ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','!','?','.','~',',','(',')','$','-',':',';',"'",'/']
doc = Document('realexample.docx')
docIndex = 0


def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None

while docIndex < len(doc.paragraphs):
    firstSen = doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text
    rep_dic = {ord(k):None for k in alphaDic + [x.upper() for x in alphaDic]}
    translation = (firstSen.translate(rep_dic))
    removeExcessSpaces = " ".join(translation.split())
    if removeExcessSpaces != '':
        doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text = removeExcessSpaces 
    else:
        delete_paragraph(doc.paragraphs[docIndex])
        docIndex -=1 # go one step back in the loop because of the deleted index

docIndex +=1
```

So the test document looks like this

```
Hello
你好

Good afternoon
朋友们
Good evening
晚上好
```

And I'm trying to achieve this result below.

```
你好

朋友们
晚上好
```

Right now the code removes all empty paragraphs and excessive spaces and does this, so I'm kinda stuck here. I only want to erase the line breaks that were caused from the English words.

```
你好
朋友们
晚上好
```

Comment: simply add another condition to the if statement to check the firstSen is empty then it will write it as it is to the file

Comment: If it is empty, then it will erase the paragraph found in the else statement.  The loop goes over all paragraph, including the line breaks (empty paragraphs), that I do not want to rid of.

Comment: I suggested you write another condition that would write the empty lines from the first file to the translated file. So you could change `if removeExcessSpaces != '':` to `if removeExcessSpaces != '' or firstSen == '':`. In that way you're saying if the empty line was originally from the file (`firstSen== ''`) then write it (or its translation, doesn't matter cause both are empty) as it is to the other file.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is looking for english words, once you find the english word "WORD", append it with "\n" and then remove this new result "WORD\n" from the document. The way you append strings in python is with + sign. Just do "WORD" + "\n"

Comment: Wouldn't that still leave the \n from the beginning?
From I'm understanding, you are suggesting to do  .......     \nWord +\n and then remove "Word\n" ?

Comment: Actually I am just suggesting to remove "word\n"

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The first word in the sentence is "\nWord", while words after that are just "Word". I'm still fumbling with that first case problem.